How to check if a collection exists in firebase database
I am developing an Installment app on Flutter, I am trying to implement the following functionality : If a product has does not have productInstallment collection then show a small container on image that Add Installment
I have completed the UI and have tried to achieve this myself but the container appears on all grids even if they have productInstallment collection in firebase
Here is database arrangement
i have users collection inside it are documnets that are users
each user document has a collection of products and categories
Inside products collection i have set of documents that are products and each document in  this collection will have productInstallments if the users adds it will appear
below is the widget responsible for showing products in Grid view
class ProductGrid extends StatefulWidget {
  final String selectedCategory;
  final String searchText;

  const ProductGrid({
    Key? key,
    required this.selectedCategory,
    required this.searchText,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ProductGrid> createState() => _ProductGridState();
}

class _ProductGridState extends State<ProductGrid> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Expanded(
      child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
            .collection('products')
            .where(
              'category',
              isEqualTo: widget.selectedCategory.isNotEmpty
                  ? widget.selectedCategory
                  : null,
            )
            .where('titlelowercase',
                isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: widget.searchText.toLowerCase())
            .where('titlelowercase',
                isLessThanOrEqualTo: widget.searchText.toLowerCase() + '\uf8ff')
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('ERROR: ${snapshot.error}');
          }

          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<Map<String, dynamic>> productsList = snapshot.data!.docs
                .map((doc) => doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)
                .toList();

            if (productsList.isEmpty) {
              return const Center(
                child: Text(
                  'No products found',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    fontSize: 18,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }

            return GridView.builder(
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                childAspectRatio: 1,
                mainAxisSpacing: size.height * 0.01,
                crossAxisSpacing: size.width * 0.017,
              ),
              itemCount: productsList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                Map<String, dynamic> productData = productsList[index];
                List<dynamic> images = productData['images'];
                String firstImageUrl = images.isNotEmpty ? images[0] : '';
                String documentId =
                    snapshot.data!.docs[index].id; // Fetching the document ID
                bool installmentPlanExists =
                    productData.containsKey('installmentPlan');

                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) =>
                            ProductDetails(documentId: documentId),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Stack(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                width: size.width * 0.29,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                                ),
                                child: ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
                                  child: firstImageUrl.isNotEmpty
                                      ? Image.network(
                                          firstImageUrl,
                                          height: 110,
                                          width: 120,
                                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                        )
                                      : const Text('Image Not Found!'),
                                ),
                              ),
                              if (!installmentPlanExists) // show a red container if the installmentPlan collection does not exist
                                Positioned(
                                  top: 5,
                                  right: 5,
                                  child: Container(
                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                    height: size.height * 0.02,
                                    width: size.width * 0.18,
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.redAccent.withOpacity(0.8),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                    ),
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Add Installment',
                                      style: customTextwhite.copyWith(
                                        fontSize: size.width * 0.02,
                                      ),
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              // else{
                              //                   Container()}, 
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.015),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  productData['title'],
                                  style: customTextblack.copyWith(
                                      fontSize: size.width * 0.035),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  ('(' + productData['quantity'] + ')'),
                                  style: customTextgreen.copyWith(
                                      fontSize: size.width * 0.03,
                                      color: productData['quantity'] == '0'
                                          ? Colors.red
                                          : secondaryGreen),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: size.width * 0.22),
                            child: Text(
                              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                              productData['price'].toString(),
                              style: customTextgreen.copyWith(
                                fontSize: size.width * 0.030,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: SpinKitDualRing(
                lineWidth: 2,
                color: Colors.blue,
                size: 35,
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}




How to check if a collection exists in a Firestore database?

There is no function available in the mobile SDK for Flutter that can help you check if a particular collection exists in Firestore. A collection will start to exist only if it contains at least one document.
If a collection doesn't contain any documents, then that collection doesn't exist at all. So that being said, you have to create a Query to check whether a collection contains or not documents.
One thing to mention is that when you do that, remember to always call limit(1). This is because if the collection contains documents, you need to limit the results to one, so you don't have to pay a read operation for each document that exists in the collection. However, if the collection doesn't exist, there is still one document read that has to be paid. So if the above query yields no result, according to the official documentation regarding Firestore pricing, it is said that:

Minimum charge for queries
There is a minimum charge of one document read for each query that you perform, even if the query returns no results.


Hey Syed. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?
